# phpunit - Run single test always last

Tags: php, phpunit

I have about 30 tests in directory `GameTests`. There is a test like `DeleteGameTest` which is based on static ID (`private const GAME_ID = '...'`) but PHPUnit runs this tests in alphabetical order.
I was tried to organise them by testsuite but 30 items in this suite makes little mess.
Is it possible to run this single test always last without setting it's name to starts with 'Z' letter?

Comment: Can we see your code.

Comment: @MarkOverton Which? phpunit.xml?

Comment: See [the docs for test dependencies](https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.3/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#test-dependencies)